# How to find the difference between a value and its closest value in a vector in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a vector like below:

```
x= c(1,23,4,15,8,17,21)
```

after sort values in vector we have:

```
c(1,4,8,15,17,21,23)
```

my required output is :

```
c(3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2)
```

Which contains the difference between the value and its closest value.

But if I want to have output without sorting, is there any solution? I need an out put like c(3,2,3,2,4,2,2) to know which sample has biggest value in output table (here 5th value is the result)

Comment: @PierreLafortune Here's how I understand the problem: take the difference between each element of the vector and any other element, return the unsigned minimum.

Comment: So basically you want a function that will subtract everything from everything and print the minimum difference of each value...?

Comment: The unsorted vector should also work with the `outer` solution I showed earlier.

Comment: What's the reason you don't want to sort? It makes any possible solution a lot more efficient.

Comment: @akrun your solution uses too much memory to be used in conjunction with other objects. Check `object.size(m1)` to see how fast it grows as `x` does.

Comment: @Heroka, Because my data has 149768 rows and 2116 columns and I want to find biggest difference in each row and then specify that biggest difference correspond to which column.

Comment: @PierreLafortune  Yes that is why I deleted it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
d <- diff(sort(x))
pmin(c(d, NA), c(NA, d), na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] 3 3 4 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: Very nice, I always forget about 'pmin'. When used on a vector of 10e5 elements (so not even that big), your solution is 38x faster than mine.

Comment: Thanks for all solutions, ...But if I want find out put without sorting is there any solution ? like as....(3,2,3,2,4,2,2).

Comment: @star, then you could use `pmin(c(d, NA), c(NA, d), na.rm = TRUE)[match(x, sort(x))]`.

Comment: @star please consider accepting this solution, for archival purposes and to stop others from spending time on an issue where a proper solution was already provided.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand you correctly, you want to calculate the smallest value between a member of a vector and it's neighbours.

First, we sort the data.

```
x= sort(c(1,23,4,15,8,17,21))
```

Then, we calculate the difference with the left neighbour (which is missing for item 1) and the difference with the right neighbour (which is missing for item 2)

```
diffs <- cbind(c(NA,diff(x)),c(diff(x),NA))
```

So, now we have the difference to the left and right for each item, now all that's left is to find the smallest:

```
res <- apply(diffs,MARGIN=1, min, na.rm=T)
```

Note that while this solution contains an explanation, other provided solutions (notably the pmin-approach by @Julius) are probably faster when performance is an issue.

Answer (score 7):

Nice solutions. Julius' seems to be the fastest:

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1262016)
x <- sample(1e5)

all.equal(heroka, NicE, julius, Ambler)
[1] TRUE

microbenchmark(

  julius = {d <- diff(sort(x))
  pmin(c(d, NA), c(NA, d), na.rm = TRUE)},

  NicE = {x <- sort(x)
  pmin(abs(x-lag(x)),abs(x-lead(x)),na.rm=T)},

  Heroka = {x= sort(x)
  diffs <- cbind(c(NA,diff(x)),c(diff(x),NA))
  apply(diffs,MARGIN=1, min, na.rm=T)},

  Ambler = {n <- length(x)
  ds <- c(
    x[2] - x[1], 
    sapply(
      2:(n - 1), 
      function(i) min(x[i] - x[i - 1], x[i + 1] - x[i])
    ),
    x[n] - x[n - 1]
  )}
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#   expr        min         lq      mean     median        uq       max neval
# julius   4.167302   5.066164  13.94478   7.967066  10.11920  89.06298   100
# NicE     4.678274   6.804918  13.85149   9.297575  12.45606  83.41032   100
# Heroka 142.107887 176.768431 199.96590 196.269671 221.05851 299.30336   100
# Ambler 268.724129 309.238792 334.66432 329.252146 359.88103 409.38698   100
```

Comment: NicE comes close in speed, but I'm a fan of solutions which don't require additional libraries.

Comment: They are essentially tied. But as the scale goes beyond one million, Julius' solution stands out more.

Answer (score 5):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- sort(x)
pmin(abs(x-lag(x)),abs(x-lead(x)),na.rm=T)
#[1] 3 3 4 2 2 2 2
```

`x-lag(x)` calculates the difference with the closest smaller number, `x-lead(x)` the difference with the closest bigger number.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do it by brute force:

```
x <- c(1, 4, 8, 15, 17, 21, 23)

n <- length(x)
ds <- c(
  x[2] - x[1], 
  sapply(
    2:(n - 1), 
    function(i) min(x[i] - x[i - 1], x[i + 1] - x[i])
  ),
  x[n] - x[n - 1]
)
```